# Minikube does not work with Virtualbox on Mac

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I'm running this command `minikube start --vm-driver virtualbox -p minikube` on `Mac` to start a minikube instance and I'm getting the following error:

```
Exiting due to IF_VBOX_NOT_VISIBLE: Failed to start host: driver start:
Error setting up host only network on machine start:
The host-only adapter we just created is not visible. This is a well known VirtualBox bug.
You might want to uninstall it and reinstall at least version 5.0.12
that is is supposed to fix this issue

 Suggestion: Reboot to complete VirtualBox installation,
verify that VirtualBox is not blocked by your system, and/or use another hypervisor
```

My version of VirtualBox is 7, I've rebooted VirtualBox and verified that it's not blocked but it's not working yet.

Any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 1):

As per the error Mac may have blocked VirtualBox during its installation, try performing below steps which will allow it:

**System Preferences >> Security & Privacy >> Allow >> Then select “allow” for the software corporation.**

After allowing it, you need to restart it. It may solve your issue.

Specify kubernetes version and VM driver while using “minikube start”

**“minikube start –vm-driver=virtualbox –kuberntetes-version=latest”**

Replace ”virtualbox” and “latest” with your driver and version. Attaching the similar [git](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/12782) issue for reference.